# Changing color of the taskbar icon

Tags: colors, taskbar, godot, gdscript

I wanted to make a software with Godot in GDScript that advice you when pressing the bloq mayus button changing the color of the taskbar icon. But, I couldn't find any special code or something that makes it.

I saw the video of Adderly Cespedes making the same software (but in gamemaker) and he said that he found a special extension for it but never said the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't currently possible in Godot.

The engine doesn't allow you to map Caps Lock (bloq mayus) to an input.

Edit: From Calinou’s comment, `OS.request_attention()` can be used to flash the taskbar.

Comment: "Nor do you have access to flash the taskbar."
This is actually supported: `OS.request_attention()`

Comment: @Calinou wow thank you. I’ve included that in the answer